# Programmatically aligning a created TButton right next to an adjacent TComponent in an FMX Frame

Tags: c++, firemonkey, c++builder

[image]

Referring to the picture, I would like to align a dynamically created `TButton` at runtime right next to a BindNavigator.

```
TButton *Add_But;
Add_But = new TButton(this);
Add_But->Visible = true;
Add_But->Text = "Add";
//Add_But->Position->X = 300;
//Add_But->Position->Y = 350;
Add_But->Parent=Form1->BindNavigator1;

Form1->Frame1->AddObject(Form1->StringGridBindSourceDB1);

Form1->Frame1->AddObject(Form1->BindNavigator1);
Form1->Frame1->AddObject(Add_But);

Add_But->Align=Fmx::Types::TAlignLayout::Right;
```

If I execute the above code, the `Add_But` button would align next to BindNavigator enclosed portion of the area between the last three buttons starting from the refresh button. Positioning `Add_But` using X,Y is not the ideal solution as I would like the `Add_But` to space out by certain margin padding just by using the `Align` property.

How to programmatically construct a `TBounds` margin object to resolve the issue?

Comment: Why are you making the BindNavigator be the `Parent` of the button if you want the button aligned next to the BindNavigator?

Comment: without this , Add button would fly to the top , in fact I solve the issue using  TFlowlayouts ,  specify the correct width , adding Navigator , follow by TButton.

Answer (score 0):

Not Optimum solution using Two FlowLayout ,Believe TGridPanelLayout is much better choice , quite difficult to code correctly at runtime on cell position placement as the Main Frame is Just An Empty container refresh to hold Any child item based on selection

```
  TFlowLayout *tlayout=new TFlowLayout(this);
    tlayout->AddObject(Form1->StringGridBindSourceDB1);
    
    
     TFlowLayout *tlayout1=new TFlowLayout(this);
    // approximate the size of the TGrid
     tlayout1->Width=600; 
    
     tlayout1->AddObject(Form1->BindNavigator1);
     Add_But->Margins->Left = 10;
     tlayout1->AddObject(Add_But);
     tlayout->AddObject(tlayout1);
    
    Form1->Frame1->AddObject(tlayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not written any apps in FMX but I saw no reason why you could not simply drop a TPanel on your FMX form then drop a TBindNavigator onto the TPanel unless there is a reason it can't be done this way, just trying to help.

This code works fine in Builder 10.3 on FMX Form

```
TButton *b = new TButton(TPanel1);

b->Parent = TPanel1;
b->Visible = true;
b->Position->X = TBindNavigator1->Width + 25;
b->Position->Y = TPanel1->Height / 2 - b->Height / 2;
b->Width = b->Width * 2;
b->Text = "Runtime Button";
```

[How it looks when you run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmaev.png)